# How can gvpr clone a graph's edges?

Tags: graphviz

I would expect that the following GraphViz *gvpr* command would copy the graph's edges, but it only copies its nodes.  What is the correct incantation to clone a graph's edges?

```
$ echo 'digraph { john -> mary }' | gvpr 'E {clone($O, $)}'
digraph gvpr_result {
        john;
        mary;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edges can be correctly cloned into a new graph.

```
BEGIN { graph_t g = graph("new", "D") }  // Initialize new directional graph
E { clone(g, $) }                        // Clone edge into new graph
END { write(g) }                         // Write new graph
```